# Jest does not parse TypeScript config file when it located in node_modules

Tags: jestjs, ts-jest

I have `service.config.ts` file localted in `./node_modules/service-configs/testing/service.config.ts`

With content:

```
// ./node_modules/service-configs/testing/service.config.ts

import type { Config } from '@jest/types';

const config: Config.InitialOptions = {
  verbose: true,
};

export default config;
```

I tried two options:

**FIRST** using `preset`

When my `jest.config.ts` looks like this:

```
export default {
  preset: './node_modules/service-configs/testing/service.config.ts',
};
```

I get an error

```
 Cannot use import statement outside a module
 /home/alexander/app/node_modules/service-configs/testing/service.config.ts:1
import type { Config } from '@jest/types';
^^^^^^
```

**SECOND** using re export

When my `jest.config.ts` looks like this:

```
export { default } from './node_modules/service-configs/testing/service.config';
```

I get an error

```
Error: Jest: Failed to parse the TypeScript config file /home/alexander/app/jest.config.ts
  SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

Comment: `export { default } from 'service-configs/testing/service.config';`

Comment: Thanks. It is a typo here. In my code i do the same as you do

Comment: I mean removing `node_modules`.

Comment: Tried remove node_modules from path, but error still occurs